# Linha de código em Unit Test que não é aceita pela cobertura de código

Tags: c#, testes-de-unidade, resharper

Tenho uma rotina de teste em que uma determinada linha de código não é aceita pela cobertura.

[image: Imagem da rotina com a linha de código que não é aceita]

Trata-se de um teste para retornar o DefaultValue já que o objeto que o chama está nulo.

Esse é o método que está sendo testando

```cs
public static TResult IfNotNull<TObject, TResult>(this TObject obj, 
    Func<TObject, TResult> action, TResult defaultValue)
{
    if (action == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

    return obj == null ? defaultValue : action(obj);
}
```

Veja que o mesmo está marcando como 100% testado.

[image: Rotina sendo testada que está marcando 100%]

Como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei qual o benefício que procura, em ter cobertura nos testes em geral (`ShouldReturnDefaultValueSinceObjectIsNull`). Certamente o seu IDE deve estar a incluir os testes na cobertura.
A cobertura deverá ser utilizada como uma ferramenta onde você pode visualizar as áreas do código que estão ou não cobertas por testes. Tenha em consideração que mesmo que a cobertura mostre que as linhas the código estão cobertas, isso não significa que o comportamento desejado da função esteja a ser testado.
Olhando nessa função/método vejo 3 comportamentos/funcionalidades que devem ser testados, se forem esses os requerimentos.

1. quando a `action` é `null` então `throw new    ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));`
2. quando o `obj` é `null` então   `return 'defaultValue';`
3. quando o `obj` não é `null` então `return 'action(obj)';`